# Loop back from today to generate a list of shifts/rota from a set template

Tags: php, laravel

I have a set of working hours and want to generate a list of suggested shifts, all based on the current 'now' time and working backwards into the past.

E.g hours template:

```php
$templateShifts = collect([
    (object)[
        "id" => 1,
        "from_day" => 1, // mon
        "from_time" => "09:00:00",
        "until_day" => 1,
        "until_time" => "12:00:00",
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 2,
        "from_day" => 1, // mon
        "from_time" => "13:00:00",
        "until_day" => 1,
        "until_time" => "17:00:00",
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 3,
        "from_day" => 2, // tue
        "from_time" => "09:00:00",
        "until_day" => 2,
        "until_time" => "17:00:00",
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 4,
        "from_day" => 4, // thur
        "from_time" => "09:00:00",
        "until_day" => 4,
        "until_time" => "17:00:00",
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 5,
        "from_day" => 5, // fri
        "from_time" => "09:00:00",
        "until_day" => 5,
        "until_time" => "17:00:00",
    ]
]);
```

If today is thursday(4th jan) it should list date in reverse order:

- Thur 09:00 - 17:00 (4th jan)
- Tue 09:00 - 17:00 (2nd jan)
- Mon 13:00 - 17:00 (1st jan)
- Mon 09:00 - 12:00 (1st jan)
- Fri 09:00 - 17:00 (31st dec)
- Thur 09:00 - 17:00 (30th dec)
- etc

This code feels horrible but I couldn't find a way of repeating a collection loop once it reaches the end without copying the code.

```php
// Paging
$total_count = 1000;
$on_page = 30;
$page = $request->get('page') ?: 1;
$skip = $on_page * ($page - 1);

// Find closest match in the past from now
$date = now();
$year = $date->year;
$weekNo = $date->weekOfYear;

$shifts = collect();

// Decrement week no
if ($skip) {
    $weekNo -= $skip;

    // Change year till positive weekNo
    while ($weekNo < 1) {
        --$year;
        $date->subYear();
        $weekNo += $date->isoWeeksInYear;
    }
}

// First page
if (!$skip) {
    // First search for shift today
    $firstShiftIndex = $templateShifts->search(function ($item, $key) use ($date) {
        return $item->from_day == $date->format('N') && $item->from_time <= $date->format('H:i:s');
    });

    $currentWeekNo = false;
    if ($firstShiftIndex === false) {
        // Loop back from today till find a matching day
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
            $date = $date->clone()->subDays(1);

            $firstShiftIndex = $templateShifts->search(function ($item, $key) use ($date) {
                return $item->from_day == $date->format('N');
            });

            if ($firstShiftIndex !== false) {
                $year = $date->year;
                $weekNo = $date->weekOfYear;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $templateShifts->slice($firstShiftIndex)->each(function ($item, $key) use ($shifts, $date, $year, $weekNo) {
        $shift_from = $date->clone()->setISODate($year, $weekNo, $item->from_day);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode(':', $item->from_time);
        $shift_from->setTime($hour, $minutes);

        // Crosses into next week/maybe year too
        if ($item->until_day < $item->from_day) {
            $weekNo++;
            if ($weekNo < 1) {
                --$year;
                $date->subYear();
                $weekNo = $date->isoWeeksInYear;
            }
        }

        $shift_until = $date->clone()->setISODate($year, $weekNo, $item->until_day);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode(':', $item->until_time);
        $shift_until->setTime($hour, $minutes);

        if ($shift_from->toDateString() == $shift_until->toDateString()) {
            $name = $shift_from->format('d/m/Y D H:i') . ' - ' . $shift_until->format('H:i');
        } else {
            $name = $shift_from->format('d/m/Y D H:i') . ' - ' . $shift_until->format('D H:i');
        }

        $shifts->push([
            'id' => $item->id,
            'text' => $name
        ]);
    });
}

//
for($i=0; $i < $on_page; $i++) {
    --$weekNo;

    if ($weekNo < 1) {
        --$year;
        $date->subYear();
        $weekNo = $date->isoWeeksInYear;
    }

    $templateShifts->each(function ($item, $key) use ($shifts, $date, $year, $weekNo) {
        $shift_from = $date->clone()->setISODate($year, $weekNo, $item->from_day);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode(':', $item->from_time);
        $shift_from->setTime($hour, $minutes);

        // Crosses into next week/maybe year too
        if ($item->until_day < $item->from_day) {
            $weekNo++;

            if ($weekNo < 1) {
                --$year;
                $date->subYear();
                $weekNo = $date->isoWeeksInYear;
            }
        }

        $shift_until = $date->clone()->setISODate($year, $weekNo, $item->until_day);
        list($hour, $minutes) = explode(':', $item->until_time);
        $shift_until->setTime($hour, $minutes);

        if ($shift_from->toDateString() == $shift_until->toDateString()) {
            $name = $shift_from->format('d/m/Y D H:i') . ' - ' . $shift_until->format('H:i');
        } else {
            $name = $shift_from->format('d/m/Y D H:i') . ' - ' . $shift_until->format('D H:i');
        }

        $shifts->push([
            'id' => $item->id,
            'text' => $name
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Am I reading it right that this is a working solution and you're looking for improvement?

Comment: Yes please I've updated with question with my latest edits and I think it working ok.

Comment: In case of working code where you're only looking to refactor/optimize, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better option.

Comment: If this were me, and the hours template object is lightweight, I would duplicate `$templateShifts` in a loop into a giant array until it holds at least `$total_count` items, then call `array_slice` at the end making sure it is exactly `$total_count` in size. Based off of your sample data and a quick test this eats 35KB of memory, totally worth it. Then you just apply standard paging logic. If hours template isn't lightweight, I'd still probably make a DTO and do this anyway, but I also hate working with date-based logic and am willing to cheat whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your expected data seems wrong, as January 4th is not an thursday (My birthday actually and that was a monday).

This is a tricky one, as there is multiple problems to tackle, i will break it down into 3 stages.

- Looping through weeks instead of days or shifts.
- Mapping your shift data, to the given week days.
- Calculating the distance to find the shift closest to the end of the
  week we are looping.

The first part, my idea is to loop through each week, figure out the shifts and subtract the date we are iterating to the next week. This is obtained with the following code. Subtracting the week is used with the Carbon methods `->subWeek()->endOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY)`.

```
$now = Carbon::parse('2021-01-04')->endOfDay();
$suggestions = collect();

while ($suggestions->count() <= 30) {
    $suggestedShifts = $this->suggestShifts($now);

    $suggestions->push(... $suggestedShifts);

    $now->subWeek()->endOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY);
}
```

The `suggestShifts()` method looks the following. Mapping all shifts to the current week, if the shift is greater than the date we are comparing to ignore it, this is only true on the first pass thou. Set the date on the shift and calculate the difference to the date we are comparing too, this will be sorted by and securing that the next shift suggested is the closets to the current date.

We are working with objects, be careful with objects are by reference, therefor i'm using one clone to avoid overwriting the same shifts. While also cloning the dates, to avoid changing the same dates over and over.

```
private function suggestShifts(Carbon $date)
{
    return $this->shifts->map(function ($shift) use ($date) {
        if ($shift->until_day > $date->dayOfWeekIso) {
            return null;
        }

        $untilTime = explode(':', $shift->until_time);
        $shift->date = $date->clone()->subDays($date->dayOfWeekIso - $shift->until_day)->setTime($untilTime[0], $untilTime[1], $untilTime[2]);
        $shift->diff = $date->diff($shift->date)->h;

        return clone $shift;
    })->filter()
        ->sortByDesc(function ($shift) {
            return $shift->date->timestamp;
        })->all();
}
```

I'm not certain this is the quickest route, but the code for this is fairly clean and readable and should get you going in the right direction. Also not that suggestions is a shift object with an date attached. My date comparison is using the until times, if you want that change to starting time you should easily be able to do that. This code was executed locally with the following results. Printing it out like so. Again note, that january 4th is a monday.

This code also returns 32 elements, i don't feel the amount is the core of the problem and you will splice the array when you figure out which way to use this approach. And `$this->shifts`, is your shift structure pasted in on a property.

```
$suggestions->each(function ($shift) {
    $this->info('Shift: ');
    $this->info('starting - ' . $shift->date->clone()->setHour(explode(':', $shift->from_time)[0])->toIso8601ZuluString());
    $this->info('ending - ' . $shift->date->toIso8601ZuluString());
});

Shift:
starting - 2021-01-04T13:00:00Z
ending - 2021-01-04T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2021-01-04T09:00:00Z
ending - 2021-01-04T12:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2021-01-01T09:00:00Z
ending - 2021-01-01T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-31T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-31T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-29T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-29T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-28T13:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-28T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-28T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-28T12:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-25T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-25T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-24T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-24T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-22T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-22T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-21T13:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-21T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-21T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-21T12:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-18T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-18T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-17T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-17T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-15T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-15T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-14T13:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-14T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-14T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-14T12:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-11T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-11T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-10T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-10T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-08T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-08T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-07T13:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-07T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-07T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-07T12:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-04T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-04T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-03T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-03T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-12-01T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-12-01T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-30T13:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-30T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-30T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-30T12:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-27T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-27T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-26T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-26T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-24T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-24T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-23T13:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-23T17:00:00Z
Shift:
starting - 2020-11-23T09:00:00Z
ending - 2020-11-23T12:00:00Z
```

Comment: There is multiple solutions to improving this, only running the greater than equal check on first iteration. The sorting by, will always be the same, so we dont have to sort it etc. Maybe i will do them, but again i feel this question is more about a cleanup and a approach to how to loop the same data over the same algorythm for now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is common loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i]['id'];
    echo $array[$i]['from_day'];
    ...
}
```

This one maybe you want:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < asYouLike; $i++) {
    
    $j = $i % count($array);           // this is the trick
    
    echo $array[$j]['id'];             //note use j for index
    echo $array[$j]['from_day'];       // j for index
    ...
}
```